# How ancient wars was actually fought?

Tags: ramayana, war

As we see on TV in serials like Ramayan, whenever a fight takes place, Two warriors would be there in a warzone against each other and they would shoot arrows at each other. The arrows would collide mid air. And whenever an opponent would want to go for a fatal strike, he would shoot arrow quickly not giving time to his opponent to even draw the arrow.
But it really doesn't feel that war might have happened this way. There is very least hand to hand combat. 
So just wanna ask if I were to image an ancient war. Would it be all about warriors throwing arrows at each other while sitting on their rath.

Comment: "The arrows would collide mid air...But it really doesn't feel that war might have happened this way." - on this site you are _required_ to believe that the war scenes happened _exactly_ the way they are described. 'How ancient wars was actually fought?' - for this, you can try [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "How ancient wars was actually fought?" can be better answered on History SE.

Comment: You should rephrase your question to ask about how Mahabharata / Ramayana mentions about wars being fought. There is hand-to-hand combat there too.